# Calling an external class object from function on main class

Tags: java, class, function, program-entry-point

I am writing a program that keeps track of different transactions
done over time. I have a main class, and also another class named 
`CheckingAccount.java`.

I have a main class formatted this way.

```
public class Main
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   { 
         CheckingAccount c = new CheckingAccount(bal);
         --line of code---
         --line of code---
         --line of code---          
   }

   public static int getTransCode()
   {
         --line of code---
   }
   public static double getTransAmt()
   {
         --line of code---
   }
   public static void processCheck(double trAm, int tCode, boolean monthCh)
   {
        double curCharge=0.15;

        CheckingAccount.setBalance(trAm,tCode,curCharge,monthCh);
        CheckingAccount.setServiceCharge(curCharge);
   }
   public static void processDeposit(double trAm, int tCode, boolean monthCh)
   {
        double curCharge=0.10;

        CheckingAccount.setBalance(trAm,tCode,curCharge,monthCh);
        CheckingAccount.setServiceCharge(curCharge);
   } 
}
```

---

This is my CheckingAccount.java

```
public class CheckingAccount
{
   private double balance;
   private double totalServiceCharge;

   public CheckingAccount(double initialBalance)
   {
        balance = initialBalance;
        totalServiceCharge = totalServiceCharge;
   }

   public double getBalance()
   {
        return balance;
   }

   public void setBalance(double tAm, int Code, double charge, boolean mChrg)
   {
        if(tCode == 1)
        balance = (balance - tAm) - charge;
        else //if(tCode == 2)
            balance = (balance + tAm) - charge;
   }

   public double getServiceCharge()
   {
        return totalServiceCharge;
   }

   public void setServiceCharge(double currentServiceCharge)
   {
        totalServiceCharge = totalServiceCharge+currentServiceCharge;
   }
}
```

So the lines I can't get to work are `CheckingAccount.setBalance()` and `CheckingAccount.setServiceCharge()` inside the functions on my main class. What I'm trying to do is to call the the methods I created (`setBalance`, and `setServiceCharge`) in my class, from functions that I created on my main class (`processCheck`, and `processDeposit`).

But I cannot get it to run, I keep running with these error messages.

> **non-static method setBalance(double,int,double,boolean) cannot be referenced from a static context
>           CheckingAccount.setBalance(trAm,tCode,curCharge,monthCh);**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling your `setBalance` through classname which is wrong.... `setBalance()` method is non-static, so it is defined to specific instance of the class, not for a class..

```
**CheckingAccount.setBalance(trAm,tCode,curCharge,monthCh);
CheckingAccount.setServiceCharge(curCharge);**
```

You need to create an instance of `CheckingAccount` to call the method..

Secondly, in your `constructor` of `CheckingAccount` class, you haven't passed any argument for `totalService`, but you are setting one with an unknown variable..
You will get a compiler error there.. 
Either you need to initialize your `totalServiceCharge` with a fixed value or, you can pass it as an argument from main.. And change your constructor as below..

```
public CheckingAccount(double initialBalance, ** double totalServiceCharge)
{
    balance = initialBalance;
    this.totalServiceCharge = totalServiceCharge;
}
```

Then from main, call it like this: -

```
CheckingAccount ca = new CheckingAccount(bal, totalServiceCharge);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solution is:

You need to create object for `CheckingAccount` before calling method.

Example:

```
public static void processDeposit(double trAm, int tCode, boolean monthCh)
   {
        double curCharge=0.10;
        CheckingAccount ca = new CheckingAccount();    
        ca.setBalance(trAm,tCode,curCharge,monthCh);
        ca.setServiceCharge(curCharge);**
   }
```

Another way is, change setBalance method as static method.

```
public static void setBalance(double tAm, int Code, double charge, boolean mChrg)
   {
        if(tCode == 1)
        balance = (balance - tAm) - charge;
        else //if(tCode == 2)
            balance = (balance + tAm) - charge;
   }
```

I think first approach makes more sense than second approach.

Answer (score 0):

`CheckingAccount.setBalance` and `CheckingAccount.setServiceCharge` are not static methods (and in this context, they shouldn't be).

You need to pass a reference of the account to your methods...

```
public static void processCheck(CheckingAccount ca, double trAm, int tCode, boolean monthCh)
{
    double curCharge=0.15;

    ca.setBalance(trAm,tCode,curCharge,monthCh);
    ca.setServiceCharge(curCharge);**
}

public static void processDeposit(CheckingAccount ca, double trAm, int tCode, boolean monthCh)
{
    double curCharge=0.10;

    ca.setBalance(trAm,tCode,curCharge,monthCh);
    ca.setServiceCharge(curCharge);
}
```

The you would be able to do something like...

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{ 
    CheckingAccount c = new CheckingAccount(bal);
    processCheck(ca, 100.0, 1, false);
}
```